# rtapmap nodes crash on Raspi 2

Tags: slam, navigation, ubuntu, raspberrypi, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS-community,

I want to start rtabmap on my raspi 2 with ubuntu 14.04 ROS Indigo. I have compiled it from Source at first like the description on github: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros. It do not worked for me, so i searched for another solution. Someone write, i need to compile it in debug mode. The compilation worked without problems after i set some more swap-space.

But when i start eg.

```
roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" rviz:=false rtabmapviz:=true
```

I get the same error and all nodes crash.

```
process[rtabmap/rgbd_odometry-1]: started with pid [3792]

process[rtabmap/rtabmap-2]: started with pid [3793]

process[rtabmap/rtabmapviz-3]: started with pid [3794]

[rtabmap/rgbd_odometry-1] process has died [pid 3792, exit code -11, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/rgbd_odometry rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_rect_color depth/image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info __name:=rgbd_odometry __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/60fe07cc-83c1-11e5-8e93-b827eb2eb151/rtabmap-rgbd_odometry-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/60fe07cc-83c1-11e5-8e93-b827eb2eb151/rtabmap-rgbd_odometry-1*.log
[rtabmap/rtabmap-2] process has died [pid 3793, exit code -11, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/rtabmap --delete_db_on_start rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_rect_color depth/image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info scan:=/scan __name:=rtabmap __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/60fe07cc-83c1-11e5-8e93-b827eb2eb151/rtabmap-rtabmap-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/60fe07cc-83c1-11e5-8e93-b827eb2eb151/rtabmap-rtabmap-2*.log
[rtabmap/rtabmapviz-3] process has died [pid 3794, exit code -11, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/rtabmapviz -d /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/rtabmap_ros/launch/config/rgbd_gui.ini rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_rect_color depth/image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info scan:=/scan __name:=rtabmapviz __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/60fe07cc-83c1-11e5-8e93-b827eb2eb151/rtabmap-rtabmapviz-3.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/60fe07cc-83c1-11e5-8e93-b827eb2eb151/rtabmap-rtabmapviz-3*.log
```

The Standalone version `rtabmap` start without problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220482/rtapmap-nodes-crash-on-raspi-2/) by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27033/gabe/) on 2016-06-02**:
Hey, I am having the same problem. Did you find any solutions? Thanks ! :)

Best,

Gabe

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-06-02**:
See this post: http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Rtabmap-error-in-process-rtabmap-rgbd-odometry-1-ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi-tp444p1246.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have the same problem as in this [post](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/Rtabmap-error-in-process-rtabmap-rgbd-odometry-1-ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi-tp444p460.html). However, there are still no solutions found yet.

Are the rtabmap_ros binaries working?

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rtabmap-ros
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch
```

**EDIT**: More info here: http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Rtabmap-error-in-process-rtabmap-rgbd-odometry-1-ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi-tp444p1246.html

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on 2015-11-07**:
Thanks for your answer!
I tried the installation from the binaries...i get the same error.
When i start other nodes like "$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmapviz"  i get the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(same problem like the guy in your link)

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-06-02**:
Have you been able to run gdb on the core dump - see where it's crashing out?